# Sprite Kit SKScene with wrong size after integrating iAd or not working at all

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad, skscene

I am trying to integrate iAd to a Sprite Kit game.

When I set "canDisplayBannerAds = true" BEFORE adding the game scene, the banner add is shown but the gameScene does not work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    canDisplayBannerAds = true

    // Configure de main view
    if let skView = view as? SKView {

        // Create and configure scene
        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // Show the scene
        skView.presentScene(scene!)
    }
}
```

[image: Result when setting canDisplayBannerAds = true before adding SKScene]

When I set "canDisplayBannerAds = true" AFTER adding the SKScene, the iAd is shown and the game scene is working now, BUT with a wrong size, bigger than the screen left after the banner is added.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure de main view
    if let skView = view as? SKView {
        skView.showsFPS = true

        // Create and configure scene
        scene = MarketGameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene!.marketGameViewController = self

        // Show the scene
        skView.presentScene(scene!)
    }

    canDisplayBannerAds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(UserDefaultsKey.ShowAds)
}
```

What am I missing?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code for you that just worked for me. This does not even need `self.candisplaybannerads = true` as I had some issues with that. The ad automatically changes the size according to the screen size and is located at the bottom of the screen. To hide and display the ads use

```
AdBanner.hidden = true/false
```

......

```
import iAd

class viewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Ad Banner Settings */

        AdBanner = ADBannerView()
        AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
        AdBanner.delegate = self
        self.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.AdBanner.frame.size.height, self.AdBanner.frame.size.width, self.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
        AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view .addSubview(AdBanner)

}

/* All iAd Functions */

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
/* whatever you need */
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    AdBanner.hidden = false
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
/* whatever you need */
    AdBanner.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}
```